# Obtaining currently connected network name (SSID) in C++

Tags: c++, ssid

I would like to obtain the name (SSID) of the wireless network that the computer is currently connected to. I've looked into the IP Helper API but it seems to have everything but that (DNS servers, IP addresses..). Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Need more info. What OS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's OS dependant, the easiest way may be to just shell out and exec the system's netsh or equivalent and then grep the result

eg. on windows 'netsh wlan show int' gives

```
There is 1 interface on the system:

    Name                   : Wireless Network Connection
    Description            : Broadcom 802.11g Network Adapter
    GUID                   : 1de52c34-2e59-46c4-ae8d-8d442c44dfd
    Physical address       : 00:00:56:b6:ad:00
    State                  : connected
    SSID                   : xxx
    BSSID                  : 00:00:5b:27:83:ea
    Network type           : Infrastructure
    Radio type             : 802.11g
    Authentication         : Open
    Cipher                 : WEP
    Connection mode        : Auto Connect
    Channel                : 6
    Receive rate (Mbps)    : 54
    Transmit rate (Mbps)   : 54
    Signal                 : 90%
    Profile                : xxx

    Hosted network status  : Not started
```

Comment: Thanks, this is probably the easiest way to do it.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use the [Native wifi](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms705969.aspx) API.  You can find samples [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa816369.aspx) (including query SSID as you asked).